# No taskbar and no task menu available on Linux Mint 20.3 (Cinnamon)

Tags: mint, taskbar

I have installed snap and tried to run the hello-world example.

My screen turn black for 1-2 seconds and now - even after a restart - I have no taskbar and no taskmenu (when pressing the "windows key" on the keyboard, nothing happens). I can still open a terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> but that's it.

Also, all desktop icons have disappeared.

How do I get it back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following steps fixed the problem:

1. Open a terminal
2. Type `cinnamon-settings`
3. Select Panel
4. Add new panel and chose one of the red lines that appear on your screen
5. Right click said panel, click trouble shoot and reset all settings to default